# Magento2 add categories and products via Module

Tags: magento2, module, import, products

I would like to create a module ,where ***i can read and excel file*** & add `products & categories` from the code. I am new to magento so `i don't now` how to get started. Setting up a new module is no problem. There a very useful tutorials on the web.

Reading my excel file is not the problem, but how can ,***i add products & categories***. Should ,i ***work with the API or directly*** with product entities ?

Is there any guide on how to add categories & products via my module code?

Comment: If you deploy an admin module you don't have to use API. Add categories from excel it's strange, i think you have to create categories from admin, then insert products with your custom module or magento standard module.

Answer (score 2):

Magento supports CSV import out of the box.

Here are several links that could help you:

- https://www.integer-net.com/importing-products-with-the-import-export-interface/
- https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/magento/import-products.htm
- http://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-exportimport-data-in-csv-files.html#gref

To import catégories, create/update is not available via excel out of the box. However there are some modules available that can do it. This is one of them: https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/bulk-category-import-export.html

**Note: You should convert your Excel files to CSV(.csv) format.**